# Multiple dialog confirm only works once

Tags: forms, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I've got this php page where I do a search which returns data from the database. The data is showed in a html table, and in each one of the items there's an option to delete the item. When I click on this delete button, it is supposed to open a dialog (I'm using jquery ui) in which I have to chose if I want to cancel or confirm the operation. Everything was working fine, then I noticed that the dialog only works in the first item of the table. When I click on the other ones, they just complete the delete operation with no confirmation. Here is the code, I'd be glad if someone could help me on this:

action.js

```
   (...)
   var buttonClicked = false;

   $(function(){           
      $('#delete').click(function(event){
          if(!buttonClicked){
              event.preventDefault();
              $('#dialogConfirm').dialog('open');                  
          }              
      });           
      $('#dialogConfirm').dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         modal: true,
         width: 250,
         height: 225,
         buttons: {
             "No": function() {    
                 buttonClicked = false;
                 $(this).dialog('close'); },
             "Yes": function() {    
                 buttonClicked = true;
                 $(this).dialog('close');
                 document.forms['formdelete'].submit();}
         }             
      });          
   });
   (...)
```

mypage.php (the relevant part of the function that generates the table)

```
(...)
function listResults($query, $num, $type) {    
if($tipo == "product") {
    if($num > 1) {
        echo "<hr>";
        echo "<h3>$num occurrences were found:</h3>";
        echo "<div id='dialogConfirm' title='Warning!'><p>Are you sure you want to delete it?</p></div>";

    echo "<table id='table1'>";
    echo "<tr><td><b>Product</b></td> <td><b>Label</b></td></tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {   
    echo "<tr id='icons'><td>" . $row['product'] . "</td><td>" . $row['label'] . "</td>
         <td><form action='#' method='POST'><button class='ui-state-default ui-corner-all' title='View'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-image'></span></form></td>
         <td><form action='editProduct.php' method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."' /><button class='ui-state-default ui-corner-all' title='Edit'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil'></span></form></td> 
         <td><form action='delete.php' method='POST' id='formdelete'><input type='hidden' name='produto' value='".$row['id']."' /><button class='ui-state-default ui-corner-all' id='delete' title='Delete'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span></form></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";         
    }
    else {
        if($num == 0) {
            echo "<h1>No occurrence was found.</h1>";            
        }
        else {
            echo "<h1>$num occurrence was found:</h1>";
            while($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo "<li>" . $array['product'] . "</li>" . $array['label'] . "<br><br>"; 
            }
        }
    } 
    (...)
```

the generated html:

```
<div id='dialogConfirm' title='Warning!'><p>Are you sure you want to delete it?</p>    </div>

<table id='table1'>
<tr>
    <td><b>Product</b></td> 
    <td><b>Label</b></td>
</tr>

<tr id='icons'><td>IBP</td><td>Dixtal</td>
<td><form action='#' method='POST'>
    <button class='ui-state-default ui-corner-all' title='View'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-image'></span></button>
</form></td>

<td><form action='editProduct.php' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='7' /><button class='ui-state-default ui-corner-all' title='Edit'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil'></span></button>
</form></td> 

<td><form action='#' method='POST' id='formdelete'>
    <input type='hidden' name='product' value='7' /><button class='ui-state-default ui-corner-all' id='delete' title='Delete'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span></button>
</form></td>

</tr>

//and then this line of the table is repeated all over again, with different values on each iteration

</table>
```

**EDIT**
Problem solved. I changed the id `delete` to a class and removed the `buttonClicked` flag from the js.

```
 $(function(){             
      $('.delete').click(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          $('#dialogConfirm').dialog('open');       
      });                     

      $('#dialogConfirm').dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         modal: true,
         width: 250,
         height: 225,
         buttons: {
             "Não": function() { 
                 $(this).dialog('close');},
             "Sim": function() {                       
                 $(this).dialog('close');                                         
                 document.forms['formdelete'].submit();
             }
         }            
      });          
   });
```

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML?

Comment: @j08691 I edited the post with the generated code :)

Comment: With your new HTML code posted, you say that that chunk of HTML is repeated over and over. Does that include the delete button with the id of delete? If so you can't re-use IDs in a document. IDs must be unique. You might be able to get away with turning it into a class instead.

Comment: thanks :) I hadn't noticed that. I changed the ids to classes and removed an useless flag and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
$('#delete').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //take event.preventDefault() out of if statement
    if(!buttonClicked){
        $('#dialogConfirm').dialog('open');                  
     }              
 });
```

It is not preventing the default behavior the second time around because it is not running the `if` statement after the `buttonClicked` var gets changed to `true`. The form just submits without the `dialog`.

The `dialog` is not opening again because when `buttonClicked` flag is `true` when `Yes` is clicked in the `dialog`.

It's hard to tell from the code what the purpose of the `buttonClicked` flag is.

Comment: @j4m It's your `if` statement. The `dialog` doesn't open because you set the `buttonClicked` to `true` when `Yes` is clicked in the `dialog`.

Comment: The buttonClicked was useless indeed. The click event is enough to trigger the dialog.